# Pointer inside a node pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures, malloc, nodes

If I create a node as below

```
struct node
{
    char *ptr = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
}*current;
void main()
{
    node *temp = new node();
    current = temp;
}
```

will the above code automatically set `current->ptr` to point where `temp->ptr` is pointing?

Comment: This is completely invalid C++ code. Please run it through a compiler with strict warnings and error checking, and update your question with the corrected code.

Comment: Your code wouldn't do either of these things, because it wouldn't compile.

Comment: Oh sorry, made a mistake. edited now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `current->ptr` and `temp->ptr` refer to the same memory address. When you instantiate the node object through `node* temp = new node()`, your temp pointer points to the newly allocated storage. The assignment of the `current` pointer through `current = temp` will simply make current point to that memory location. Note that object pointed to by `current` still exists elsewhere in memory (along with the MAX sized character array) since we have not free'ed that memory. Also, pointer assignment does not copy the object - it merely makes a pointer point to a different memory location. Referencing any member of the objects pointed to by `current` and `temp`, will, in fact, return the same values - whether they are pointers or other types.

Your code is currently invalid and will not compile. This is a fixed version of what you intend to do.

```
#include<cstdlib>
#include<cstdio>

#define MAX 10

struct node
{
        char* ptr;
        node()
        {
           ptr = new char[MAX];  // Do not use malloc if using new elsewhere. 
        }

}*current;

int main()
{
    struct node* temp = new struct node();
    current = temp;

    // The pointer addresses will be the same. 
    printf("Current->ptr=%p, temp->ptr=%p\n", (void*)current->ptr,  (void*)temp->ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Precision of answer at it's best. (y)

Answer (score 3):

```
struct node
{
    char *ptr = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)); // INVALID
} *current;
```

First of all, you should not mix memory models.  If you are using `new`, stick with `new`.  Do not bounce between `new` and `malloc`.

Second, this is not valid C++.  You cannot declare a class member and call a function to initialize it in the declaration (unless you are using C++11's new features).  Updating it to clean it up would look something like:

```
struct node
{
    char* ptr; // declare the pointer
    node() : ptr(new char) { } // initialize the pointer in the constructor
    // NOTE:  should also add a copy constructor and copy-assignment operator here
    ~node()
    {
        delete ptr; // free the memory in the destructor
    }
};

int main() // NOTE that main must return an int, not void
{
    node current = new node();
    node temp = *current; // will do a shallow copy
    // ...
    delete current;
    // PROBLEM - temp now has a dangling pointer!
    return 0;
}
```

Also note that there is no reason why `ptr` has to be a pointer in this case.  Since you are just dynamically allocating a single `char`, you can just use an automatic:

```
struct node
{
    char data;
    node() : data('\0') { }
};

int main()
{
    node current;
    node temp = current; // temp now has a copy of data, no problems
    return 0;
}
```

> will the above code automatically set current->ptr to point where
>   temp->ptr is pointing

The code you have will not even compile, but if you made the fixes, the default copy-assignment operator will do a shallow copy.  In the case with the pointer, this will mean you have 2 objects both pointing to the same memory location.  Since they both assume they own it, when one of them destroys it, the other is left with a dangling pointer.

Comment: In my actual code I have to allocate `max*sizeof(char)` memory , so it is mandatory for me to use malloc.

Comment: @SrujanBarai `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be always 1. There’s no reason to ever use `malloc` instead of `new` (except when interfacing with very badly designed legacy libraries), and there’s no reason in modern C++ to use `new`, even.

Comment: @SrujanBarai `char* data = new char[max]` - Unless this is for homework where the professor is telling you to use `malloc` (for some strange reason), you do not have to use `malloc` to do this.

Comment: @SrujanBarai You do not need to use malloc. just use an array of characters with the size of max.

Comment: And also, `char *ptr = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));` might be orthodox, but is NOT invalid. It's working fine in my code!

Comment: @SrujanBarai yes it works. but it comes from C not C++. if you use classes later you will get into trouble. C++ uses new to allocate memory.

Comment: @SrujanBarai `char* ptr = ...;` is fine, *by itself*.  `struct X { char* p = ...; };` is invalid (unless you are using C++11, which you do not have tagged).  [Example](http://ideone.com/nxqQL5)

Comment: Well, for a moment if we accept memory allocation just the way i've done, I simply want to know if changing reference of a `current` pointer to `temp` will also change the `current->ptr` to point `temp->ptr` ?

Comment: @SrujanBarai The last paragraph of my answer gives you the answer to that question.

Comment: @ZacHowland Exactly,This is what even i thought of, but what is happening with my code is, when i do `current=temp` and add values to `*current->ptr`, `current->ptr is still refering to old node instead of referring to temp. This quite bewildered me.

Comment: @SrujanBarai Note that if you, for example, change the value of the pointer `temp->ptr` to point to something else, `current->ptr` will not be updated to point to the new item.  When you set `current = temp` it does a shallow copy of the data, so `current->ptr` points to the same location as `temp->ptr` as long as you don't change the value for either of those pointers.  Once you change the value of the pointer (e.g. `temp->ptr = new char[5];`) they no longer point to the same memory location.

Answer (score 1):

current and temp refere to the same place in the memory. so actually current->ptr **is** temp->ptr.

Comment: Actually when I execute my code, the `current->ptr` does not change its reference when I change the reference of `current`.

Answer (score 1):

After this statement where assignment operator is used

```
current = temp;
```

current and temp will have the same value. This value is the address of an object of type node where it was allocated. So the both pointers point to the same memory occupied by the object. The object itself was not copied or moved.

Operator new returns an address of the memory where it allocated an object not the object itself. So after this statement

```
node *temp = new node();
```

variable temp will have this address and after

```
current = temp;
```

the both current and temp will store this address.

Comment: what is happening with my code is, when i do current=temp and add values to *current->ptr, `current->ptr` is still refering to old node instead of referring to temp. This quite bewildered me.

Comment: The both variables refers to the same node. So *current->ptr = 'A'; is equivalent to *temp->ptr = 'A'; temp and current have the same value,